TALLY XML API Issue
In tally xml api when we get the list of companies and we get the status of them, like active for current using company and inactive for which we are not using.
How can we get the status of it or how do we identify the active company??
Currently ian using this schema for this.
Request object:

<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>Collection</TYPE>
        <ID>List of Companies</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <COLLECTION NAME="List of Companies" ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="Yes" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No">
                        <TYPE>Company</TYPE>
                        <NATIVEMETHOD>Name</NATIVEMETHOD>
                    </COLLECTION>
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>


refer this xml

In the link which you provided it is getting the active companies , i need it in list of them and in that list should be able to find the active company or the current company

You can use the logic in that, instead of filtering add it is a field if yes then active company else not
